# negative width and hight of Actor/Sprite in LibgGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, bounds, scene2d

Say you have an `Actor` using `Scene2D` and you set the `Bounds` to negative width and height. The `Actor` will be drawn correctly, but the interaction is lost. All the `ClickListener`'s `Events` will not trigger any more. How can you adjust `LibGDX` to work correctly with negative widths and heights. If this would not be possible, alternative solutions would also help.

Comment: why do you need negative heights and widths?

Comment: You could override `setWidth` and `setHeight` methods of the `Actor` to set positive bounds like this: `void setWidth(float width) { if (width < 0) { setX(getX() + width); super.setWidth(-width); } else { super.setWidth(width); }`

Comment: @desertkun that was what i thought about, but i wanted to know first why he needs that to be sure that this solves his problem. Anyway you should post it as an answer, i think that is what he is looking for. +1